# How to branch from a label?

Tags: version-control, tfs, branch

TFS tells me I don't have permission when I try to branch from a label. However, I was able to branch from the latest code and then roll my branch back to the desired label.

I have every imaginable permission I could find to give myself. What do I need to be able to just branch directly from a label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be operator error. I was trying to branch from the wrong place.  wouldn't have thought it would have showed me the label I made for another project but I guess all labels show up no matter what they apply to.